# Selecting one item closes the other dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

The following code opens both the Admin and Actions dropdown groups. However, when you click on an item in either group, the other dropdown closes. Is there a way to resolve this issue? I would greatly appreciate any advice from anyone who can help.

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" width="300">
    <v-list v-model:opened="open">
      <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-close"></v-list-item>

      <v-list-group value="Admin">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Admin"></v-list-item>
        </template>

        <v-list-item
          v-for="([title], i) in admins"
          :key="i"
          :title="title"
          :value="title"
        ></v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>

      <v-list-group value="Actions">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Actions"></v-list-item>
        </template>

        <v-list-item
          v-for="([title], i) in cruds"
          :key="i"
          :value="title"
          :title="title"
        ></v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      open: ['Admin'],
      admins: [
        ['Management', 'mdi-account-multiple-outline'],
        ['Settings', 'mdi-cog-outline'],
      ],
      cruds: [
        ['Create', 'mdi-plus-outline'],
        ['Read', 'mdi-file-outline'],
        ['Update', 'mdi-update'],
        ['Delete', 'mdi-delete'],
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `open-strategy` prop as `multiple`.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```js
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" width="300">
    <v-list v-model:opened="open" open-strategy="multiple">
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
```